# Closing ftp-connection in filezilla

Tags: ftp

If I am connected to a server, is it ok to just shut down filezilla? Does filezilla make a disconnect in a proper way?

Answer (score 2):

While it does not matter how you close the FTP connection in FileZilla, you may let the connection timeout, close the window, or manually close the connection via this icon in the menu:

[image: Close FileZilla Connection]

Answer (score 1):

The connection between the server and filezilla will eventually time out.